# Spring3 namespace error

Tags: namespaces, spring-3

I am new to Spring 3. I don't know how to fix this namespace error in Spring `security.xml`. Actually I am tying to add profile code around a bean, so whenever I add

```
<beans:beans profile="dev">
```

around any bean, it throws the following error: 
**Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'context:component-scan'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is 
     expected.
    - advised by org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)**

Here is the code of .xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


   <beans:beans profile="dev">  **( This is code that generates error)**
    <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1xsd">


   <beans:beans profile="dev">  
    <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we put a single  declaration at below any nested  tags we will get the exception

Have a look at this article

http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/

also make sure the beans node is the last element in the file 
http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/